# Why cannot I iterate through string objects line by line

Tags: python, string, list

I have a text file with string objects on each line. I can iterate through the file line by line. But accessing each object individually gives me an error.

My files look as follows.

> > ('19.04.17','[{"fields": {"a": 5, "b": 1}, "tags": {"device": "PM""}, "series": "q"}]') ('19.04.19','[{"fields": {"a": 5, "b": 1},
> >     "tags": {"device": "PM""}, "series": "q"}]') ('19.04.21','[{"fields":
> >     {"a": 5, "b": 1}, "tags": {"device": "PM""}, "series": "q"}]')

I can read the file line by

```
with open('data') as f:
      lines = f.readlines()
```

This gives output as each line. When I do `type(lines)` I get but I would like read each object separately from lines object. For example `obj1 =  '19.04.17'` and

```
obj2 = '[{"fields": {"a": 5, "b": 1}, "tags": {"device": "PM""}, "series": "q"}]'
```

I tried doing `json.loads(lines)` but I get it expects a string or buffer.

On doing `type(lines)` I get

> type 'list'

Comment: your question is not clear. you have written `When I do type(lines) I get` twice. please edit and clear your question.

Comment: `lines` after calling `f.readlines()` is a `list`, which won't parse properly with `json.loads`. What I would do is iterate over the file directly and use `json.loads` for each line, which would be a `str`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to @DroidX86's answer, you can use the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module as an alternative for `json`:

```py
import ast

with open('data') as f:
    lines = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in f]
```

However, `ast` is most useful for evaluating data types, such as tuples, whereas `json` is more optimized for parsing actual json, which is a more tightly constrained format. You definitely get better performance from `json` than `ast`:

```py
python -m timeit -s 'import json; x = "{\"1\": 2}"' 'json.loads(x)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.09 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s 'import ast; x = "{\"1\": 2}"' 'ast.literal_eval(x)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.08 usec per loop
```

`ast` will most benefit you when trying to evaluate data *types* which are not valid json, which is your case here

Answer (score 2):

Each line may be `json`. But the list containing all the lines isn't

```
objects = []
with open('data') as f:
    for line in f:
        objects.append(json.loads(line))

print(objects)
```

Comment: for some reason this solutions didn't work. ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: Your strings are not json then. You can catch the exception and try to handle it